# Writing string at the same position using Console.Write in C# 2.0

Tags: c#, .net

I have a console application project in C# 2.0 that needs to write something to the screen in a while loop. I do not want the screen to scroll because using Console.Write or Console.Writeline method will keep displaying text on console screen incremently and thus it starts scrolling.

I want to have the string written at the same position. How can i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use [Console.SetCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx) to set the position. If you need to determine it first, use the [Console.CursorLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cursorleft.aspx) and [Console.CursorTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cursortop.aspx) properties.

Comment: Works a treat, if you have already "written" a line you can just keep doing `Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1); Console.WriteLine(progress);` to "update the same line from the start...

Answer (score 4):

Function to write the progress of a loop.  Your loop counter can be used as the x position parameter.  This prints on line 1, modify for your needs.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Writes a string at the x position, y position = 1;
    /// Tries to catch all exceptions, will not throw any exceptions.  
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s">String to print usually "*" or "@"</param>
    /// <param name="x">The x postion,  This is modulo divided by the window.width, 
    /// which allows large numbers, ie feel free to call with large loop counters</param>
    protected static void WriteProgress(string s, int x) {
        int origRow = Console.CursorTop;
        int origCol = Console.CursorLeft;
        // Console.WindowWidth = 10;  // this works. 
        int width = Console.WindowWidth;
        x = x % width;
        try {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, 1);
            Console.Write(s);
        } catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e) {

        } finally {
            try {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(origCol, origRow);
            } catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```