# Rewriting characters in command window

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to output some characters in C# console application and then rewrite them, thus changing characters in position already occupied in command window. So for for example I could show progress in percentages 10%, 20%, 30% (but in the same place). How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Writing string at the same position using Console.Write in C# 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283669/writing-string-at-the-same-position-using-console-write-in-c-2-0)

- [Console.SetCursorPosition Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx)
- [Console.CursorLeft Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cursorleft.aspx)
- [Console.CursorTop Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cursortop.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you print a '\r' character, the cursor will return back to the current line, e.g.

```
Console.Write("10%\r");
// then..
Console.Write("20%\r");
```