# Can I clear specific text from the console?

Tags: c#, text, console

I try to build a game and I always clear the screen but that makes it lag. So, to make it not lag, can I clear specific text?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rewriting characters in command window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370695/rewriting-characters-in-command-window)

Comment: I think the odds of getting a clean refresh in a command line app, even with replacing text, will be very slim. Have you pondered a WPF RichTextBox approach? It's not super performent either, but it's easy and won't flicker.

Comment: i make snake so the location of the text always change

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove only one last char then simply use `console backspace` **\b** char

```
Console.Write("\b");
```

If you want to clear only one char,You can use `Console.SetCursorPosition(int, int)` to reach that point then the write empty

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 1, Console.CursorTop);
Console.WriteLine(" ");
```

To remove more than one char, you can store the current `Console.CursorLeft` in a variable and use that value in `Console.SetCursorPosition(--variablename, Console.CursorTop)` in a loop to delete many chars you want!

For Example:- if You want to delete Current Console Line Then

```
public static void RemoveCurrentConsoleLine()
{
    int currentCursorLine = Console.CursorTop;
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth)); 
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, currentCursorLine);
}

Console.WriteLine("Top 1 Line");
Console.WriteLine("Top 2 Line");
Console.WriteLine("Top 3 Line");
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
```

Then Output Will be only top 2 lines. third line will be deleted:-

```
Top 1 Line
Top 2 Line
```

[For more information Refer Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx)