How do I stop the user from being able to scroll the console?
I'm programming a console app in Visual Studio in windows. Part of my design is that the current information is displayed towards the top of the screen, and the user gets prompted to input a command below it that modifies the data. The command code works perfectly.
Name: Example Name
Images: 0
Videos: 0
Gifs: 0

Comics: 0
Collections: 0

Total: 0






>

I would like to only have this information on the screen, but the user is still able to scroll the console up and see previous information and I don't know why.
This is the method I use to do it a class called "ConsoleBottom.cs"
public static (bool Success, string Response) DisplayContentAndGetResponse(List<string> linedDisplayContent, string promptText, int promptLineNumber) {
    if (promptText.Length > Console.WindowWidth) return (false, "");
    if (promptLineNumber < 0 || promptLineNumber > Console.WindowHeight) return (false, "");

    Console.Write("\x1b[2J");
    Console.Clear();

    // only write as many lines as can fit on the screen
    int smaller = int.Min(linedDisplayContent.Count, Console.WindowHeight);

    for (int i = 0; i < smaller; i++) {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, i);
        Console.Write("\x1b[2K");
        Console.Write(linedDisplayContent[i]);
    }

    // Clear prompt line and write prompt
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, promptLineNumber);
    Console.Write("\x1b[2K");
    Console.Write(promptText);

    string? response = Console.ReadLine();
    response ??= string.Empty;

    return (true, response);
}

Even with the Console.Clear() and Console.Write("\x1b]2J"); I am still able to scroll up and see previous information in the terminal.
What is the best way to change the console behavior in my app so that the user cannot scroll?

Why are you concerned with what users can see in the console? Or in other windows open in their system of choice? If you want to control what the users see from your app then display only that information.

I want to be able to change the behavior of the console the app is running in. My plan was to have the screen show relevant information and prompt the user at the bottom, then when the user is done the information changes and the user gets prompted again.

If that's what you want to do, why are you messing in the console? Write a proper GUI with an input control and a text box for output.

Because I like the console and I don't know any libraries.

In addition to what Tangentially Perpendicular says: if you want to limit what the user can see, you are just using the application type and technique that totally mismatches your goals. If you answer that you just like the console and don't know something, it means you know better what you need, but then your question makes no sense. You need to be able to identify problems that should not be solved.

Also, you may want to do a completely different thing: use the technique still based on System.Console but writing strings to the same positions. You can do it using System.Console.SetCursorPosition.
See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283669/writing-string-at-the-same-position-using-console-write-in-c-sharp-2-0.
Please let me know if you like the idea or think it is questionable. (I personally would not bother doing such things.)

"I've tried clearing the screen with Console.Clear(); ... to remove all text and simply write to the screen buffer, but both only move the buffer so that the previous text is above it; The user is still able to scroll using this method."  I find that hard to believe. Clear() literally clears the screen. You appear to be displaying a tiny amount of information, but keep talking about a "buffer". How are you outputting information on the screen? Something doesn't seem quite right here...

Just make the console buffer size the same as the console window size so there is nothing to scroll.  Look here
